# Show the number of page in titlepage

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I don't know why the number of pages is not shown:

> "Number pages :??"

Here is a picture:

[image]

My main

‎

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,msc]{SBU}‎
‎\input{commands}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\frontmatter‎
‎\thispagestyle{empty}‎
‎\begin{figure}‎
‎\centering‎
‎\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{besm}‎
‎\end{figure}‎
‎\vfill‎
‎\clearpage‎
‎\newpage‎
‎\thispagestyle{empty}‎
‎‎\pagenumbering{adadi}‎
‎\input{fa_title}‎
‎\include{preface}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎

‎\tableofcontents‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎

‎\listoftables‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎

‎\listoffigures‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎

‎\mainmatter‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{chapter1}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{chapter2}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{chapter3}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{chapter4}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{conclusion}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\backmatter‎
‎{\small‎
‎{\baselineskip=.75cm‎
‎\include{dicfa2en}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{dicen2fa}}‎
‎\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}‎
‎\include{references}‎
‎}‎

‎\input{en_title}‎
‎\label{LastPage}‎
‎\end{document}
```

"And My English Title"

‎

```
\baselineskip=.6cm‎
‎\begin{latin}‎
‎\latinuniversity{ University}‎
‎\latinfaculty{Faculty of Mathematical Sciences}‎
‎\latindegree{M‎. ‎Sc‎. ‎}‎
‎\latinsubject{Department of Mathematics}‎
‎\latinfield{Computer Science}‎
‎\latintitle{Solving Fractional Differential Equations }‎
‎\firstlatinsupervisor{Dr‎. ‎Kourosh }‎
‎\firstlatinadvisor{Dr‎. ‎Ali }‎
‎\latinname{Mah‎‎}‎
‎\latinsurname{Alone‎}‎
‎\latinthesisdate{2013}‎
‎\latinkeywords{Spectral Methods‎, ‎Fractional Defferential Equations‎,‎Chebyshev functions}‎
‎\en-abstract{\noindent‎
‎Computer Sciences are a connection between knowledge of Computer and Mathematics‎.  ‎‎‎‎}
‎
‎\latinvtitle‎
‎\end{latin}‎
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are Right. I dont have time to read the hole "Working example"  Please help me. Why the number of pages is not shown?

Comment: Your document class is unknown.

Comment: Editing the question tags doesn't help us in finding a solution for your problem. You have to reduce your code to something that reproduces the problem and that other people can compile (your document class `SBU` is not a standard document, so we cannot try out your code).

Comment: Probably you just need to typeset a few more times, w/o changing the pagination so that the number of pages will stabilize, be captured in the .aux file and then input so as to be placed on the page.

Comment: Check your `.log` file for warning messages, the "number of pages" look like an undefined reference. If running LaTeX at least twice does not help, then you should post a pointer to the class file somewhere. Because it seems that the class file is responsible for the number of pages.

Comment: Which order write the "number of page " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run pdflatex twice? It needs at least two runs to find a value for the label. However you will only get a useful number if your pages are numbered 1, 2, ... until the last page. If you switch the numbering (e. g. to i, ii, iii) somewhere, it breaks and you just get the page number of the last page (not the total count).

There's a package that can help in the latter case: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts